# Why can't I pip install packages in my main Python installation folder? Virtualenv getting in the way?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper-win`. Now when I have 3 locations for Python albeit one of them is a `.bat`. See?

```
C:\>where python
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\env\Scripts\python.bat
C:\env\Scripts\python.exe
```

Also, when I try installing new libraries with `pip` they end up going into

```
C:\env\Lib\site-packages
```

For example I just did `pip install Flask`, opened up Python interpreter and tried to import it like so:

```
>>> import Flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Flask
```

So I guess my question is, why does `C:\env` even exist? It was a while back when I installed `virtualenv` and I think the `env` dir was created then. Anyways, I would like to be able to install packages to my main Python installation located at `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` or is that not a wise move? I hear people should always use `virtualenv`. I'm open to suggestions on how to solve this issue and best practices.

Also I never could get `virtualenvwrapper-win` to work. The author of it told me that it would not work because it thought that my system's main installation of Python was located in `C:\env\Scripts\python.exe`

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening without more info. Is `env` where your virtualenv was installed? Try renaming `env` to some other name (or just delete it if you don't want the virtualenv any more), then install Flask again and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know in windows.. but in Linux I would guess you're with the virtualenv activated "pip install" will install in the env. If you want to install in the system python you'll have to use `sudo` (inside or out the virtualenv)

Comment: @alan well, I see `virtualenv.exe` located in `c:\env\Scripts\`. How come it was not installed in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`?

Answer (score 0):

You use virtualenv to organize different versions of Python and packages for project. For example, An older project may use python 2.7 and newer projects 3.1. If you use virtualenv you can seperate the site packages. And both of the projects can still run on the same system.

Virtualenv helps with deploying as well. You can only move the env folder from your local to server, and keep the primary python project in tact.

It is mostly used for organizing multiple python projects on one system.

[virtualenv What It Does](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#id4)